# Secret site for moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

Is there some dedicated place like "moderator.puzzling.stackexchange.com" where moderators discuss things?

Or some kind of chat instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is a moderator-only chatroom.

<s>Found the puzzling one: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21276/</s>

^Bot room for posts that might need the mods.

**The site wide moderator-only chatroom is here:** http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge

Comment: Oh, that one's not actually the link to the main Puzzling mod chatroom. It's a side room for stuff we might want to take a look at.

Comment: @Emrakul Oh. So what's the link to the real one? And the one for all SE mods? :P

Comment: Somewhere on Stack Exchange... ;)

Comment: @Emrakul http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge

Comment: That was the result of searching for 'moderator chatroom', and then finding the abbreviation 'TL'. Then I had to search for mod chat and TL, and then I found a link. :P